# Unable to extract text in a list with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to extract information from this page: https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/list?consumer=-1

More specifically the text in the first row under 'Subject'. See here: `//*[@id="main-content"]/app-list-component/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/app-nt-list-item[1]/div/div[4]/p`

Does anybody have an idea  how to do so? I've tried numerous ways but results always comes empty. It looks like a dynamic list...

Below is the last thing I've tested.

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='//chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/list?consumer=-1")

subject = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="main-content"]/app-list-component/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/app-nt-list-item[1]/div/div[4]/p')

print(subject)

driver.quit()
```

Thank you very much in advance! As you can see, I'm not very skilled at this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Carlos Abundancia, you need to read the text attribute of the web element. So if you change the following lines in your code:

```
print(subject)
```

to:

```
print(subject.text)
```

you should get your output. Also I suggest you should put explicit wait for the subject element as it takes some time to load and I was getting NoSuchElementException. So my code version with wait is:

```
driver.get("https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/list?consumer=-1")
subject = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content"]/app-list-component/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/app-nt-list-item[1]/div/div[4]/p')))
print(subject.text)
driver.quit()
```

you will need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

- *`subject`* is the WebElement returned through `driver.find_element()`. Instead of printing the element itself, you need to print it's text.
- The desired element may not be redily available within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). So you need to wait a bit.

---

### Solution

To extract and print the text ***Salmonella in raw chicken from Latvia*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/list?consumer=-1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Accept all cookies"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results-list-body>app-nt-list-item>div div[class*='item-subject']>p"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/screen/list?consumer=-1')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Accept all cookies"))).click()
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='results-list-body']/app-nt-list-item/div//div[contains(@class, 'item-subject')]/p"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Salmonella in raw chicken from Latvia
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)